# Deriving a type and its dependencies

Tags: haskell, typeclass, derived-types, deriving

I've been playing with newtype wrappers for my indexes to avoid bugs, and I have some code like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype PersonIdx = PersonIdx Int
  deriving (Enum, Eq, Integral, Num, Ord, Real, Show)
```

To derive `Integral`, one must derive all its dependencies as well (hence the above list of type-classes).

Is there a way to make it derive all the dependencies of `Integral` along with it? I would imagine something like:

```
newtype PersonIdx = PersonIdx Int
  deriving (Integral(..))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no shortcut. You'll have to derive from all dependent typeclasses explicitly, but can easily find these by typing `:i Integral` in ghci.

Comment: I wonder if there's a principled reason for this, or simply that no one has implemented the shortcut in question.

Comment: It is somewhat in the philosophy of Haskell that everything be explicit. There are very few "shortcuts" in the language, and this example is no exception.